# Using Node JS project as a VPN service

Tags: node.js, proxy, vpn, openvpn

I know it's very uneccessary but i want to learn it is possible or not. Can i connect to my Node js project to use like a proxy, like a vpn? I can't access server shell of node js project so i can't setup openvpn or something. I want to connect my Node js project with remote device and surfing on the internet, using Node JS project as VPN.